# How to check table weather is has been filled or not?

Tags: javascript, html, button, click, html-table

I have one html page which gets generated as a result of clicking of search button on the page.  Which fetches the records from mySQL and populate the table but after that it has one plot which uses the search parameter as input and plot the graph using highcharts.

**Structure of page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#plotgenerator").click(function(e){
        $.ajax();
    });
    </script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
       <input type=TEXT value="" name="text">
       <input type=SUBMIT value="search" name="search">
       <table></table>
       <input type=SUBMIT value="Submit" name="plotgenerator">  /*click button and fetch records using Ajax and generate a plot here.*/
     <div id ="someplot"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Once table gets populatated button plotgenerator should be clicked and plot should be generate here. How to check the table has already been filled and completed?

Comment: You can use this in jquery to check if the table has got any rows `if($('table').find('tr').length > 0){ ...`

Comment: How is your table populated? Is it also with an ajax call? If so, you could use the success method on the ajax call.

Comment: no it is simply populated using mysql fetch commnd.

Comment: But if i check for any row then plot will started after filling one row only. (Pls correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: But where to write this ($('table').find('tr').length > 0){ ... command

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks the table before the search. Your `$(document).ready` runs in the moment the user opens the page. If you use '`$(document).on` it may checks the table after the search, when the results are there.